# Dualbooting gone wrong

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, 18.04, windows

so I had a dualboot system with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 on the same disk. On startup I could choose between those two options.
Config:
sda1 + sda2 windows, sda3 ubuntu sda4 swapp

Now I've formatted the Ubuntu partition and installed Ubuntu Mate 18.04.1. I had to try multiple times, because I could no longer boot into Ubuntu, just into Windows. Since Ubuntu is my main system and windows is "just" for gaming, this was unacceptable. In the Internet there was a recommondation to use a single partition for /boot/efi. That worked. But I cannot boot into Windows anymore. With grub-customiser I've tried to manually boot from sda1 or sda2 with the chainloader option, but it does not boot. boot-repair didn't help me as well.

What can I do?

boot-repair log (the start and suggested repair, couldn't post all of it)

```
 Boot Info Script 8f991e4 + Boot-Repair extra info      [Boot-Info 25oct2017]


============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    for (,msdos7)/boot/grub. It also embeds following components:

    modules
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    fshelp ext2 part_msdos biosdisk
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 => Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    for /boot/grub. It also embeds following components:

    modules
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    fshelp ext2 part_msdos biosdisk search_fs_uuid
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

    config script
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    search.fs_uuid 59884c5a-97a1-4a0d-803b-f08754c18b38 root hd0,msdos7 
    set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'

    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /Boot/BCD

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /Windows/System32/winload.exe

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       Extended Partition
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg /EFI/BOOT/fbx64.efi 
                       /EFI/ubuntu/fwupx64.efi /EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi 
                       /EFI/ubuntu/mmx64.efi /EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi

sda6: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       swap
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda7: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab 
                       /boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sdb2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________
Disk /dev/sda: 119.2 GiB, 128035676160 bytes, 250069680 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1    *          2,048       206,847       204,800   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda2             206,848   134,424,575   134,217,728   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda3         134,426,622   250,068,991   115,642,370   5 Extended
/dev/sda5         249,679,872   250,068,991       389,120   b W95 FAT32
/dev/sda6         241,483,776   249,679,871     8,196,096  82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda7         134,426,624   241,481,727   107,055,104  83 Linux


Drive: sdb _____________________________________________________________________
Disk /dev/sdb: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sdb1               2,048   976,562,175   976,560,128  83 Linux
/dev/sdb2         976,562,176 1,953,523,711   976,961,536   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS


"blkid" output: ________________________________________________________________

Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/loop0                                              squashfs   
/dev/loop1                                              squashfs   
/dev/loop2                                              squashfs   
/dev/loop3                                              squashfs   
/dev/loop4                                              squashfs   
/dev/loop5                                              squashfs   
/dev/sda1        2A305B70305B424D                       ntfs       System-reserviert
/dev/sda2        DE3C69153C68EA4B                       ntfs       
/dev/sda5        9B1A-75A3                              vfat       
/dev/sda6        676623b7-4e0b-4ed9-a0a9-22f6dc833e98   swap       
/dev/sda7        59884c5a-97a1-4a0d-803b-f08754c18b38   ext4       
/dev/sdb1        aeed298b-9fde-4f02-a35e-a40d56ed5fe5   ext4       
/dev/sdb2        2FC71E081224AF73                       ntfs       windata

========================= "ls -l /dev/disk/by-id" output: ======================

total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Aug 30 19:53 ata-HL-DT-ST_DVDRAM_GH24NS95_K51CBNB2036 -> ../../sr0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Aug 30 21:06 ata-M4-CT128M4SSD2_0000000013020924D0E6 -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Aug 30 21:06 ata-M4-CT128M4SSD2_0000000013020924D0E6-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Aug 30 21:06 ata-M4-CT128M4SSD2_0000000013020924D0E6-part2 -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Aug 30 21:06 ata-M4-CT128M4SSD2_0000000013020924D0E6-part3 -> ../../sda3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Aug 30 21:06 ata-M4-CT128M4SSD2_0000000013020924D0E6-part5 -> ../../sda5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Aug 30 21:06 ata-M4-CT128M4SSD2_0000000013020924D0E6-part6 -> ../../sda6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Aug 30 21:06 ata-M4-CT128M4SSD2_0000000013020924D0E6-part7 -> ../../sda7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Aug 30 21:06 ata-ST1000DM003-1CH162_S1D7T6XN -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Aug 30 21:06 ata-ST1000DM003-1CH162_S1D7T6XN-part1 -> ../../sdb1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Aug 30 21:06 ata-ST1000DM003-1CH162_S1D7T6XN-part2 -> ../../sdb2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Aug 30 21:06 wwn-0x5000c5005be2ac23 -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Aug 30 21:06 wwn-0x5000c5005be2ac23-part1 -> ../../sdb1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Aug 30 21:06 wwn-0x5000c5005be2ac23-part2 -> ../../sdb2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Aug 30 19:53 wwn-0x5001480000000000 -> ../../sr0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Aug 30 21:06 wwn-0x500a07510924d0e6 -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Aug 30 21:06 wwn-0x500a07510924d0e6-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Aug 30 21:06 wwn-0x500a07510924d0e6-part2 -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Aug 30 21:06 wwn-0x500a07510924d0e6-part3 -> ../../sda3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Aug 30 21:06 wwn-0x500a07510924d0e6-part5 -> ../../sda5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Aug 30 21:06 wwn-0x500a07510924d0e6-part6 -> ../../sda6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Aug 30 21:06 wwn-0x500a07510924d0e6-part7 -> ../../sda7

================================ Mount points: =================================

Device           Mount_Point              Type       Options

/dev/sda1        /media/micha/System-reserviert fuseblk    (ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,uhelper=udisks2)
/dev/sda2        /media/micha/DE3C69153C68EA4B fuseblk    (ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,uhelper=udisks2)
/dev/sda5        /media/micha/9B1A-75A3   vfat       (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,showexec,utf8,flush,errors=remount-ro,uhelper=udisks2)
/dev/sda7        /                        ext4       (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
/dev/sdb1        /home                    ext4       (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
/dev/sdb2        /media/micha/windata     fuseblk    (ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,uhelper=udisks2)


========================== sda5/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg: ===========================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
search.fs_uuid 59884c5a-97a1-4a0d-803b-f08754c18b38 root hd0,msdos7 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=========================== sda7/boot/grub/grub.cfg: ===========================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="0"
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}
function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}
function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,msdos7'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos7 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos7  59884c5a-97a1-4a0d-803b-f08754c18b38
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 59884c5a-97a1-4a0d-803b-f08754c18b38
fi
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=de_DE
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=30
else
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=menu
    set timeout=10
  # Fallback normal timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
  # unavailable.
  else
    set timeout=10
  fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
if background_color 60,59,55; then
  clear
fi

color_normal=light-gray/black

if [ -e ${prefix}/themes/ubuntu-mate/theme.txt ]; then
  insmod png
  theme=${prefix}/themes/ubuntu-mate/theme.txt
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
    if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=1
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
}
if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-59884c5a-97a1-4a0d-803b-f08754c18b38' {
    recordfail
    load_video
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos7'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos7 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos7  59884c5a-97a1-4a0d-803b-f08754c18b38
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 59884c5a-97a1-4a0d-803b-f08754c18b38
    fi
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-33-generic root=UUID=59884c5a-97a1-4a0d-803b-f08754c18b38 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-33-generic
}
submenu 'Erweiterte Optionen für Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-59884c5a-97a1-4a0d-803b-f08754c18b38' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, mit Linux 4.15.0-33-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.15.0-33-generic-advanced-59884c5a-97a1-4a0d-803b-f08754c18b38' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos7'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos7 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos7  59884c5a-97a1-4a0d-803b-f08754c18b38
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 59884c5a-97a1-4a0d-803b-f08754c18b38
        fi
        echo    'Linux 4.15.0-33-generic wird geladen …'
            linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-33-generic root=UUID=59884c5a-97a1-4a0d-803b-f08754c18b38 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Initiale Ramdisk wird geladen …'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-33-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, mit Linux 4.15.0-33-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.15.0-33-generic-recovery-59884c5a-97a1-4a0d-803b-f08754c18b38' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos7'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos7 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos7  59884c5a-97a1-4a0d-803b-f08754c18b38
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 59884c5a-97a1-4a0d-803b-f08754c18b38
        fi
        echo    'Linux 4.15.0-33-generic wird geladen …'
            linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-33-generic root=UUID=59884c5a-97a1-4a0d-803b-f08754c18b38 ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Initiale Ramdisk wird geladen …'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-33-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, mit Linux 4.15.0-32-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.15.0-32-generic-advanced-59884c5a-97a1-4a0d-803b-f08754c18b38' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos7'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos7 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos7  59884c5a-97a1-4a0d-803b-f08754c18b38
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 59884c5a-97a1-4a0d-803b-f08754c18b38
        fi
        echo    'Linux 4.15.0-32-generic wird geladen …'
            linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-32-generic root=UUID=59884c5a-97a1-4a0d-803b-f08754c18b38 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Initiale Ramdisk wird geladen …'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-32-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, mit Linux 4.15.0-32-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.15.0-32-generic-recovery-59884c5a-97a1-4a0d-803b-f08754c18b38' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos7'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos7 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos7  59884c5a-97a1-4a0d-803b-f08754c18b38
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 59884c5a-97a1-4a0d-803b-f08754c18b38
        fi
        echo    'Linux 4.15.0-32-generic wird geladen …'
            linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-32-generic root=UUID=59884c5a-97a1-4a0d-803b-f08754c18b38 ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Initiale Ramdisk wird geladen …'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-32-generic
    }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
menuentry 'System setup' $menuentry_id_option 'uefi-firmware' {
    fwsetup
}
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
menuentry "Windows sda1"{
    set root='(hd0,1)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set 2A305B70305B424D
    drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
    chainloader +1
}
menuentry "Windows sda2"{
    set root='(hd0,2)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set DE3C69153C68EA4B
    drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
    chainloader +1
}
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
=================== Suggested repair
The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would reinstall the grub2 of sda7 into the MBRs of all disks (except live-disks and removable disks without OS).
Grub-efi would not be selected by default because: no-win-efi
Additional repair would be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s   fix-windows-boot
```

Comment: Just run the summary report, the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
Boot Repair -Also handles LVM, GPT, separate /boot and UEFI dual boot, only use ppa download into Ubuntu live installer.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: done - pasted into the initial request

Comment: You have new UEFI based hardware, but Windows installed in the now 35 year old BIOS/MBR configuration. Microsoft has required vendors to install in UEFI mode for 5 years, but since UEFI can emulate BIOS, users can install in old configuration. But you then forced an install of Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode. UEFI & BIOS are not compatible. UEFI really should be on gpt drive, but BIOS Windows only boots from MBR. Reboot Ubuntu installer in BIOS mode, add Boot-Repair and install the grub-pc (BIOS version of grub) to convert install to BIOS boot.Or totally reinstall Windows in UEFI mode.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I guess installing in BIOS mode is my preferred way.  But I am quite unsure right now. I booted my Ubuntu Usb in BIOS mode and installed boot repair and grub- pc. On booted repair in advanced mode I have 2 options: reinstall grub or restore MBR. What do I do know? I thought I will do kind of both?

Comment: And just to be sure: repair tool from Windows will not upgrade the Windows boot to uefi?

Comment: I do not think it is easy to convert Windows to UEFI as you also have to convert to gpt partitioning. Best just to reinstall if that is what you want. For Ubuntu you have to uninstall grub-efi-amd64 which is for UEFI boot and install grub-pc which is for BIOS boot. Once you have grub-pc installed, sometimes you only need to reinstall grub to MBR. Note Windows 10 uses fast start up which is hibernation & grub does not boot hibernated Windows. And Windows with updates turns it back on. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions

Comment: Thanks mate, the problem is solved, I am able to boot into Windows and into Ubuntu.

Comment: How ever I was not able to uninstall UEFI boot, my system told me it was not installed. And somehow my /dev/sdb (HDD) has still an UEFI boot, but when I boot from /dev/sda (SSD) it's legacy boot as intended. Simple fix in the BIOS boot order. How can I mark this question as answered?